# Gandhi tells us what we do to others we also do to ourselves?

Tags: commas

> Gandhi tells us what we do to others we also do to ourselves.

Shouldn't there be a comma here between 'to' and 'others'? Can this sentence be considered grammatically correct even without the comma ?

Comment: Please cite a source.

Comment: I see no justification at all for including a comma. But you could make the text a bit easier to parse by including relativizer ***that*** between *Gandhi tells us* and *what we do...*

Comment: Check out written instances of the sequence [***that what we do to others***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that+what+we+do+to+others%22&tbm=bks&ei=VWdfZO3MFpnNgQbM76TICg&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwity_nzi_L-AhWZZsAKHcw3CakQ8NMDegQIDxAU&biw=1280&bih=635&dpr=3) - virtually all of which will match your context. It looks to me as though between 1 in 5 and 1 in 10 include a comma after ***others***. The vast majority don't. And almost *by definition*, most of those texts are relatively older, so given commas are used less often today anyway, the preference is even greater than suggested there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the grammar as it is written. Adding a comma where you suggest would be wrong. However as a side note, I can't find that quote attributed to Ghandi anywhere at all, which is unsurprising. It seems to be a mangled version of the Golden Rule: Do to others as you would have others do to you, or treat others as you would like others to treat you, or some variant of that. However, it's worded so poorly that it's patently absurd

Comment: Do you mean a comma between "others" and "we"? It makes zero sense where you suggest it

Answer (score 1):

A source of that sentence would be good to have, and, in that same vein, someone could have spelled what they think Gandhi said wrongly.

That matter aside, *the sentence is grammatically correct as it is, as it can't be misinterpreted.*

A comma between 'to' and 'others', as you suggest, does not make sense in any case, because 'to' is a preposition modifying the noun 'others', and they are inseparable.

On the other hand, a comma between 'others' and 'we' might improve readability, but is not necessary.

Comment: You might feasibly put a comma between 'others' and 'we' (I wouldn't, anyway), but the OP suggests putting a comma **between 'to' and 'others'**, which would *never* make sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I completely missed that, having assumed the comma suggested by the OP would be between 'others' and 'we'. I'll edit that in, thanks!

Comment: I cancelled my downvote, but I still think someone needs to understand and explain why the OP might have mistakenly thought a comma was "grammatically correct" (or even *necessary*). And to "improve readability", you just need to include ***that*** after *Gandhi tells us...***